# Solving system of nonlinear equations

Tags: r

I am trying to solve system of non linear equations:

```
# K = N + M
# M = log(1 + i*FS*(1 - r)/r)/log(1 + i)
# N = log[1/(1 - FS*i/(1 + i))]/log(1 + i)
# Numerically solve the above system of nonlinear equations
# Variables: N, M, FS
# Parameters (external, given): K, r, i
```

I tried to solve this using package nleqslv in the following way:

```
require(nleqslv)

NMfun<-function(x, K, r, i) {
    y <- rep(NA, length(x))

    y[1] <- K - x[1] - x[2]
    y[2] <- x[1] - log(1 + i*x[3]*(1 - r)/r)/log(1 + i)
    y[3] <- x[2] - log(1/(1 - x[3]*i/(1 + i)))/log(1 + i)

    return(y)
}

K <- 80
r <- 0.70
i <- 0.06
xstart <- c(20, 60, 60)

NMfun(xstart, K, r, i)

nleqslv(xstart, NMfun, K=K, r=r, i=i)
```

I get an error when running the above:

```
> NMfun(xstart, K, r, i)
[1] 0.000000 3.983082      NaN
Warning message:
In log(1/(1 - x[3] * i/(1 + i))) : NaNs produced
> 
> nleqslv(xstart, NMfun, K=K, r=r, i=i)
Error in nleqslv(xstart, NMfun, K = K, r = r, i = i) : 
  evaluation of fn function has non-finite values
   (starting at index=3)
In addition: Warning message:
In log(1/(1 - x[3] * i/(1 + i))) : NaNs produced
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `log(1/(1-60*0.06/(1+0.06)))` does not exist.  You have a log of a negative number inside the function.

Comment: Try a different starting value e.g. xstart <- c(20,1, 15). You need to make xstart[3] small enough to ensure that the argument to log() is positive.

Comment: :) Thanks @RScriv and Bhas. It was 3AM here when I finally gave up... It works perfectly now when being careful/smart about xstart.